# What is the correct way to set up and display a JavaScript alert message in ASP .NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm completely new to working with JavaScript in ASP .NET so bear with me.

Say I have the following:

```
protected void btnCreateReplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      doSomething();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      //How do I display the error? I know if I were in WinForms, I could just do this:
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
   }
}
```

First question:

1. Should I put all of my JavaScript code in a .js file in my ASP .NET solution?
2. If so, how do I call an alert message from the .js file?
3. If not, how do I call an alert message instead of the MessageBox.Show?

Comment: Note that, while this is fine for development, it's not particularly standard to do this for production environments in a web paradigm.  Normally you'd log the errors to a log file somewhere and then either redirect the user to an error page or just include the error text somewhere on the screen.  Since it's not even convenient to code (the way it is for winforms) it's not even used by a lot of people for development either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` method.

```
string script = "alert('We had an error')";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), 
    "myErrorKey", script, true);
```

`RegisterClientScriptBlock` takes a type, a key to see if the script block is already registered, the script, and a boolean indicating whether the method should add the `script` tags, or if you're string script variable already includes them.

Comment: The second parameter of `RegisterClientScriptBlock` takes a `key`, which is a string. When you call the method, it will check the key to see if your script is already registered on the page. If it is not, it will add it, otherwise it will ignore it. I named that one "myErrorKey", but you can call it whatever you want. The point is to have different `keys` for each script block you register.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Appreciate the help. I will accept your answer but I have to wait 5 mins and I gotta run out. I'll hit you back later today. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

as Dave said, using the tScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock method, you can inject the javascript into your page and have it run.

If you want to make the alert a bit more complex, it is cleaner to use a StringBuilder to set up the script.

Here, a link! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Comment: If your script is going to be complex you should probably just specify it in a javscript file, or at least in the markup rather than the code behind.  Usually it's best for javascript called in code behind to be either really short, or just a call to a function defined in one of those other more appropriate mediums.

Comment: Typically, but when your script only has 16 lines of code(random low number, not specific) and you need to pass data from your c# into js variables, it is an efficient way as well. For example, in displaying an alert for an Error, displaying error information that you can't easily access from the client side, it is fairly simple to get that information placed in the script block, pushing a good solid function for displaying and setting data over only when it is needed. Your point is taken, if it's going to be complex, there are other ways to do it without cluttering the code behind

Answer (score 0):

Another helpful way to show JavaScript alerts would be to use `OnClientClick` in .ASPX page. This is similar to `OnClick` for ASP Classic if you are familiar with ASP.

```
OnClientClick="alert('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

This may not be helpful for you for above code but can use to show other simple alerts.